# ive been trying to make the prompted site run in an iframe but idk how

Tags: javascript

```js
(function() {
  let url = prompt("what site do you want to open?");
  let win = window.open(url, '_self');
  win.document.body.style.margin = '0';
  win.document.body.style.height = '100vh';
  var iframe = win.document.createElement('iframe');
  iframe.style.border = 'none';
  iframe.style.width = '100%';
  iframe.style.height = '100%';
  iframe.style.margin = '0';
  iframe.src = url;

  win.document.body.appendChild(iframe);
})();
```

so how does one make the iframe run in the current site you are on (if you are on google drive, the prompted iframe will run on google drive)

Comment: Your code works as it is (providing `win` is defined). Only that many web sites don't allow you to load them into an iframe.

Comment: What is `win`? There is no such variable.

Comment: Now after you've added the value of `win`, the code works with pages from the same domain only. Open an empty pop-up, and append the iframe to that document.

Comment: ok I edited the thing a bit

Comment: ok so my goal was to make it so you can run it and it would be undetectable by school bypasses and their spyware, with and about:blank, they auto close it. I get there is nothing really to do so thanks yall!

Answer (score 1):

You ask the user for a URL that you use to open a new window. You then attempt to create a new element in that window. However, browsers only allow you to modify the content of iframes loaded from the same origin as the parent page. If you use `about:blank` for the URL of the opening page, it should™ work, but I can't test it right now because the internet is being spotty and I barely posted this answer.

```js
(function() {
  let url = prompt("what site do you want to open?");
  let win = window.open("about:blank", "_self");
  win.document.body.style.margin = '0';
  win.document.body.style.height = '100vh';
  var iframe = win.document.createElement('iframe');
  iframe.style.border = 'none';
  iframe.style.width = '100%';
  iframe.style.height = '100%';
  iframe.style.margin = '0';
  iframe.src = url;

  win.document.body.appendChild(iframe);
})();
```